# REDIS: How to intersect set into list

Tags: redis, intersect

Is is possible with Redis to intersect two normal sets & record the result into list.

I have multiple products with features.

I need to intersect the products by the features & show only small portion of them with for example LRANGE

Now I have:

```
SMEMBERS feature1 -> product1, product2, product3
SMEMBERS feature2 -> product2, product3, product4

SINTERSTORE mycache feature1, feature2 -> product2, product3
```

Doing `SMEMBERS mycache` Takes significant amount of time (over 1 million products).
But I need only 20 products a time.

If `mycache` was list I would easly do `LRANGE 0 20` to get only the first 20 products.

Comment: have you considered using a SQL database instead?  I should be more flexible for joins and getting subsets like you describe.